# Does 「決めることにしています」 = 「決めます」?

Tags: grammar, nuances, tense

In [this NHK News Easy](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10014014291000/k10014014291000.html) article, the final sentence says:

豊明市は職員たちに意見を聞いて、この働き方をこれからも続けるか決めることにしています。

After asking a native, a good translation for the second phrase would apparently be "[Toyoake City] will decide whether to continue this way of working."

But what I'm curious about, is that the ことにする pattern already includes a meaning of "decide to". So, does 「決めることにしています」 mean "has decided to decide"? The English sentence simply uses future tense, so how would just using 「決めます」 change the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that ことにしています makes it explicit that the decision will take place (substantially) *in future*. I suppose it is similar between *to decide to decide* and *to decide* if the former is not idiomatic in English.

For the sentence

- ...決めることにしています

means *We are planning to decide*, implying that there's still some time for the decision.

- ...決めます

would mean, in this context, practically the same, but it may sound *we take the questionnaire now (or in the near future) and make a decision*.

---

For comparison

- 試着をしてから買うかどうか決めることにしています
- 試着をしてから買うかどうか決めます

When you are talking to a shop clerk, normally the latter is used. The former would sound 'I make it a rule that I buy clothes/shoes after trying them'. This should be because 試着 does not usually take long, so that it can't mean 'I've decided to decide whether to buy it or not (say) in 10 days after trial'. In other words, in case of trying clothes, the final decision shouldn't be too far and using ことにしています would sound a bit odd to talk about a particular instance of decision.

Answer (score 2):

The verb being 決める shouldn’t affect how you should understand 〜ことにしている.

In this particular sentence, what they will decide (決める) is whether or not to continue the current way of working (この働き方をこれからも続けるか). What has been decided (ことになっている) is that that decision will be based on what they hear from the employees (職員たちに意見を聞いて〜決める). The sentence would sound like something is missing if you removed 職員たちに意見を聞いて.

> ? 豊明市はこの働き方をこれからも続けるか決めることにしています。

The sentence would be still correct if you removed 〜ことにしている.

> 豊明市は職員たちに意見を聞いて、この働き方をこれからも続けるか決めます。

This is a firm statement about what they will do, and based on what, and doesn’t explicitly say anything about what has already been decided.